# Parse for Android: ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get(KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN) returns null

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, token

Parse for Android: Trying to get a device token in Parse but it keeps returning null. This code was working about 6 months back but lately have noticed this issue. Using the device token to subscribe to Parse later on. It just gets stuck in the while loop.I am using Parse 1.7.1 version. Even if I update the parse will this be the right way to get the device token?

```
private static final String KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN = "deviceToken";
boolean isTokenReady = false;
while (!isTokenReady) {
    String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get(KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN);
    if (!StringHelper.isNullOrEmpty(deviceToken)) {
        isTokenReady = true;
    } else {
        sleep(1000);
    }
}
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("pushtoken_" + deviceToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, if you are retrieving a String:

```
ParseInstallation.getQuery().get(objectId).getString(KEY_DEVICE_TOKEN)
```

If you need to get the objectId from the default installation class:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getObjectId();
```

I'm using version 1.9.2. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's been 11 updates of the Android parse sdk. I would definitely update since there's lots of fixes.

Also, you shouldn't have to block your thread to wait for the device token. Did you forgot to save the installation before trying to get the deviceToken?

Like this:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().save();
String deviceToken = (String) ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get( "deviceToken" );
```

Lastly, Im not sure why you would use a unique device token as push channels. You can use the deviceToken directly. So I would suggest not to subscribe to any channels and push notifications to selected devices using their deviceTokens.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on this problem too...
getInstallationId() seems to work. I use installationId to query installations and now it works OK